# why the twitter is redirecting when the page does not exists.

Tags: php, twitter

In this code why the twitter site is redirecting when the requested page `www.twitter.com/misc/drupal.js` does not exists in the site `www.twitter.com`. Why the status is not `404`.

```
<?php
    include    ("HttpClient.class.php");
    $client    =    new HttpClient('www.twitter.com');
    $client*enter code here*->setDebug(true);
    $client->get('/misc/drupal.js');
    echo $client->getStatus();
?>
```

Output: 301 Moved Permanently.

Comment: You don't need to use the backticks (`) when indenting your code block with four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting www.twitter.com. To keep with their short theme, they don't use www before their domain name. You are getting the 301 redirect because Twitter is asking you to request http://twitter.com/misc/drupal.js instead of http://www.twitter.com/misc/drupal.js. Try:

```
<?php
include('HttpClient.class.php');
$client = new HttpClient('twitter.com');
$client->get('/misc/drupal.js');
echo $client->getStatus();
?>
```